# How to understand change of units of y-axis in a simple plot of $y(x)=x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the relationship $y(x)\ \text{meter}=x\ \text{meter}$ and let the unit meter be called m.

This is a straight line with slope $1\frac{\text{m}}{\text{m}}$ if we make a plot of $y$ versus $x$.

Suppose we would like to make the plot of $y$ centimeters versus $x$ meters.

$$y\ \text{m} = x\ \text{m}\tag{1}$$

$$y\cdot\mathrm{10^2cm}=x\ \text{m}\tag{2}$$

$$y\ \text{cm}=10^{-2}x\ \text{m}\tag{3}$$

In (3), as far as I can tell, $y$ is just a number and it is multiplying the unit cm. On our plot, the vertical axis represents $y$, the amount of the unit cm.

We want the horizontal axis to be the amount of the unit m. This is the number $10^{-2}x$. Thus, the horizontal axis is represents the variable $z=10^{-2}x$.

$$y\ \text{cm} = z\ \text{m}\tag{4}$$
$$y\ \text{cm} = z\cdot 10^2\ \text{cm}\tag{5}$$

(5) seems to be the desired result.

When $z=1$, then $y=10^2$.

For some reason, however, I am still not satisfied with my understanding of the units in the reasoning above. It all seems correct, but when I say that "when $z=1$ then $y=10^2$", can I actually say "when $z=1\ \text{m}$ then $y=10^2\ \text{cm}$"? I don't think so, and yet, the plot of (5) seems to be of a quantity $y$ in cm versus a quantity $z$ in m.

I have made a distinction between a "pure" number and units. When I wrote $z=10^{-2}x$ there were no units, so how can I speak of $z\ \text{meters}$ in (4)?

It seems to be the case that whenever we plot something the units must be the same on both sides of the equation. We can't plot (4) but we can plot (5).

**I think my question boils down to:** when we have a function that we wish to plot, how do we know the units of the plotted variables? In particular, where are the units of $z$ established/defined/determined in the equations above?

**Here is another example, where I change the units of $y$ instead of $x$**.

Consider a resistance

$$R=\frac{v\ \text{V}}{i\ \text{A}}=10^3\mathrm{\frac{V}{A}}\tag{6}$$

The current through the resistance is

$$i\ \text{A}=\frac{v\ \text{V}}{R}=v\ \text{V}\cdot 10^{-3}\ \mathrm{\frac{A}{V}}\tag{7}$$

We can make a plot of $i\ \text{A}$ versus $v\ \text{V}$, but suppose we would like to change to $i\ \text{mA}$ where $1\ \text{mA}=10^{-3}\ \text{A}$.

Then we would do

$$i\ \text{A}=i\cdot 10^3\ \text{mA}=10^{-3}\mathrm{\frac{A}{V}}\cdot v\ \text{V}\tag{8}$$

We want to plot the quantity $i\cdot 10^3$ against $v$. If we define $z=10^3i$ then we have

$$z\ \text{mA}=10^{-3}\mathrm{\frac{A}{V}}\cdot v\ \text{V}\tag{9}$$

but we can't plot this yet (and one of my questions is why exactly not?). We have to make the units on both sides the same. In particular, this means converting A to mA on the right.

$$z\ \text{mA} = 1\mathrm{\frac{mA}{V}}\cdot v\ \text{V}\tag{10}$$

So the slope is 1.

Comment: Can you clarify that $x,y,z$ are "pure" numbers with no unit? How do you expect $y$ and $z$ to be related?

Comment: As in, do you wish to say "when $z=1$" or "when $z=1\text{ m}$", as you did both after $(5)$? The first case would instead mean $z=1 \iff z\text{ m} = 1\text{ m}$. Similarly $y=10^2 \iff y\text{ cm}=10^2\text{ cm} = 1\text{ m}$.

Comment: My question is precisely about such clarifications, which I don't have. The result I obtained in (5) is the result I expect. We started with $y(x)=x$ in meters, and if we change $y$ to cm then I would expect that when $x$ is 1 meter, then $y$ is 100 cm. My difficulty seems to be the following. Consider equation (2). Does $y$ have a unit in that equation? It seems like the answer is no, what has a unit is the entire expression $y\cdot 10^2$. In fact, if I use $z=10^2\cdot y$ then $z$ now has the unit cm and we have $z\ \text{cm}=x\ \text{m}$. $x$ has units m, and yet we can't plot this yet.

Comment: It seems to me that in the example from the previous comment, $z$ by itself has no units. It is assigned a unit only in equation (2).

Comment: I would say that, in $(2)$, if $y$ has no unit, then $y\cdot10^2$ is also a number that has no unit. The entire LHS expression $y\cdot10^2\text{ cm}$ is (probably) a length that has a unit.

Comment: I agree $y\cdot 10^2$ is also a number, and when we put it on lhs of (2) then the entire lhs is now a number with a unit. When we plot a function, it seems we are plotting a variable with a unit versus another variable with a unit. Thus, if we wanted to plot (2), we could plot $z\ \text{cm}=y\cdot 10^2$ cm versus $x$ m, which has slope 1. But actually, what I was looking for is the plot of $z\ \text{cm}=y\cdot 10^2$ cm versus $x$ m but in the expression $10^2 x$ cm. My doubt is about the difference between $x$ m and $10^2 x$ cm, because in the latter $x$ m seems not work out algebraically.

Comment: Thus, $x$ in $10^2\ \text{cm}$ seems to be just a number after all.

Comment: I still don't have a good answer after these hours, but I would summarise as "find the unknown multiplier $\square$ below". Eq. $(1)$-$(3)$: $$\text{Given $y=x$,}\\
\text{Satisfy $y\text{ cm} = \square\cdot x\text{ m}$.}\\
\text{($\square=10^{-2}$)}$$
Eq. $(4)$-$(5)$:
$$\text{Given $y\text{ cm}=z\text{ m}$,}\\
\text{Satisfy $y= \square\cdot z$.}\\
\text{($\square=10^2$)}$$
Which one is your problem in mind?

Answer (score 0):

I would summarise as "find the unknown multiplier $\square$ below". Then the question is, which of the following is your problem in mind?

From eq. $(1)$-$(3)$:

$$\begin{align*}
&\text{Given} & y&=x\\
&\text{Satisfy} & y\text{ cm} &= \square\cdot x\text{ m}\\
&& \square &=\frac{y\text{ cm}}{x\text{ m}}\\
&&&= \frac{x\text{ cm}}{x\text{ m}}\\
&&&=10^{-2}
\end{align*}$$

From eq. $(4)$-$(5)$:

$$\begin{align*}
&\text{Given} &  y\text{ cm}&=z\text{ m}\\
&\text{Satisfy} & y&= \square\cdot z\\
&& \square&=\frac yz\\
&&&= \frac{y\text{ cm}}{z\text{ cm}}\\
&&&= \frac{z\text{ m}}{z\text{ cm}}\\
&&&= 10^2
\end{align*}$$

---

Such apparent conflict when scaling units had become a first example of [active and passive transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation) for myself.

Answer (score 0):

You have tacitly provided a number of constants that appear unitless but aren't. For example in the equation $y\cdot\mathrm{10^2cm}=x\ \text{m}$ it's actually $y \cdot (10^2 \frac{\text{cm}}{\text{m}}) \text m = x \text{ m}$. This is non-trivial and can't be ignored. Note that the units are in centimeters per meter, the defining quality of a centimeter. In fact, the $x$ and $y$ in this equation are completely unnecessary, it's just $10^2 \text{cm} = 1 \text{m}$. The meters and centimeters themselves are constants, not variables and we need to be careful not to blur that distinction.

This also reveals the flaw with the equation $y \text{ cm} = z \text{ m}$ since $1 \text{ cm} \neq 1\text{ m}$ It's tempting to think of a conversion as a function but I think it's more accurate to interpret it as a substitution of constants. This is because nothing is actually changing other than how we choose to label the measurements.

When plotting functions there is a variable we can adjust which is the length along each axis to which we ascribe some unit. There is no requirement that these spacings be consistent or uniform. Sometimes distorted scales can be useful such as with a [logarithmic scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function). So there is a distinction here between a function and how we draw its graph. We have some freedom to choose the shape by choosing this labeling which will impact the shape of our plot.

So there will be two functions involved in the plot, one for each axis which tells us how to draw the units relative to the graph. Lets call these variables that ascribe a unit to a position along each axis $p_x$ and $p_y$ respectively. These position or spacing functions are what determines the shape of the graph. In fact using this we can distort the plot of the identity function $f(x)=x$ so that it doesn't resemble a line at all.

While these functions can be rather general we do need to impose an important restriction on them which is that they be [strictly monotonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function), and by convention we choose them to be increasing. This ensures that the function respects the ordering so we can compare values along each axis meaningfully. We should also be able to convert back and forth between units which implies $p_x$ and $p_y$ should be invertible. However since strictly monotonic functions are always invertible this condition is redundant.

To build some intuition I'd recommend plotting some functions where the $p_x$ function equally spaces each point and let the $p_y$ function vary while plotting the same function. Some simple examples of strictly monotonic increasing functions like $e^t$ and $t^3$ will change the shape of the identity function in a natural way. You may want to do this by hand rather than using a computer since it's a lot simpler than trying to code variable axes. Once that pattern is clear to you try look at some familiar functions like $x^2$ and $\sin x$ on a logarithmic scale. From there try some more exotic choices for $p_y$ and try interpret how it influences the shape of the graph.